# Check for update within android application not on Google Play

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm pretty much new to android coding, so I'm sorry if I make some mistakes while asking the question.
I'm trying to implement in-app updates for a personal use application and not to be put up on the play store. I've searched my way through stack and found various methods through which that can be achieved. So I tried my own. But the thing is, it doesn't work sometimes, and sometimes it shows wrong information about the update being available. To be more specific, when I compare the curVersionCode to newVersionCode, where curVersionCode = newVersionCode, it still shows that the newer version is available.

Here's My Activity -

```
public class Test extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.front);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        checkUpdate.start();
        }
    }

    /* This Thread checks for Updates in the Background */
    private Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL updateURL = new URL("URL TO THE TXT FILE");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(updateURL.openStream()));
                String str;
                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
                /* Get current Version Number */
                PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
                int curVersion = packageInfo.versionCode;
                int newVersion = Integer.valueOf(str);

                /* Is a higher version than the current already out? */
                if (newVersion > curVersion) {
                    /* Post a Handler for the UI to pick up and open the Dialog */
                    mHandler.post(showUpdate);
                }

                }
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

    };

    /* This Runnable creates a Dialog and asks the user to open the Update Link*/
    private Runnable showUpdate = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(BrowserActivity.this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setTitle("Update Available")
                    .setMessage("An update for is available!\n\nOpen Update page and see the details?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("URL TO THE UPDATE FILE"));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            /* User clicked Cancel */
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
    };
```

Been searching for a few days, still ain't able to find the answer. I'm sorry if this is a basic question but I'm pretty new to it.

Thanks.

**EDIT** : The code now works just fine. Turns out it requires some time to refresh the version code over the internet text file. Doesn't matter, got experience.

Comment: do you check what is the value of  'int newVersion' ?? may be in your service it is not returning the correct value

Comment: @Sree It is providing the correct version, for example, if the version in the TXT file is 27, it shows 27 as the newVersionCode. Also, if the curVersionCode is 27, it shows that an update is available.

Comment: then where is your problem?

Comment: @Sree Well, the update is to be shown only when newVersionCode > curVersionCode, but the update shows even when newVersionCode = = curVersionCode